# C++ Builder 6 - global paths for include directories

Tags: development-environment, c++builder-6

Is there a way to set global paths (i.e. independent from currently opened project) to include directories?

Answer (score 3):

You can open the ide, set the directories's and libraries's paths and others options that you might want and check "Default" checkbox. Close all, dont need to save. That way your future projects, by default, will include those directories and options that you set for global use

Answer (score 0):

Not for Include paths, no.  Those are project-specific.  There is "Tools > Environment Options > Library" for global Library paths, however.